# 'HashAlgorithm' does not contain a definition for 'Create'

Tags: c#, encryption, asp.net-core, password-encryption

I landed up in this situation!

I used to use this function in my **MVC 5 app**:

```
public virtual string CreateHash(byte[] data, string hashAlgorithm = "SHA1")    
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(hashAlgorithm))
       hashAlgorithm = "SHA1";

    var algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create(hashAlgorithm);


    var hashByteArray = algorithm.ComputeHash(data);
       return BitConverter.ToString(hashByteArray).Replace("-", "");
}
```

Now I am creating an app **in ASP.NET Core**. and **I find the error**.

Also with `RNGCryptoServiceProvider()` function, there was a same issue. but I used `RandomNumberGenerator()` instead. but I am not able to find any workaround for this!

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use `SHA1.Create()`, to reproduce the original `HashAlgorithm.Create()` you have to write down your own mapping dictionary from string to static factory method to call.

Comment: I tried using `var algorithm =  SHA1.Create();` and it works fine... Tysm!

Comment: but if I need to select a different algorithm, is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documented bug [#22626](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22626), will NOT be fixed.

Workaround is:

```
public static HashAlgorithm Create(String hashAlgorithm) {
    return (HashAlgorithm) CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(hashAlgorithm);
}
```